# Redundancy of the Cantor enumeration of the rationals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

What is the cardinality of the set of values corresponding to the first $n$ rationals generated in Cantor's enumeration scheme for proving their countability?

Edit:
following the [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204536/redundancy-of-the-cantor-enumeration-of-the-rationals#comment508412_204536) of Todd, here I integrate the clarification from the comments here:
By "Cantor's enumeration scheme" I mean the one, that Cantor originally used (I am however not aware, which that was, so that would also be part of the question).
In case of doubt, sort the fractions according to numerator+denominator or, in case of equal sum, accoding to numerator/denominator in ascending order in both cases.

As the rationals, whose value is encountered for the first time, are those for which numerator and denominator are relatively prime and because the probability that two natural numbers are relatively prime, is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, it would not be suprising if the number of different values encountered in the first $n$ fractions of the Cantor sequence would approach $n\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, so the interesting question is, whether the exact value of the factor for a given $n$ can be calculated or at least the asymptotic growth.

Comment: Hm, just how standardly understood is this scheme? One formula is given by the inverse of the function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ sending $(m, n)$ to $\binom{m+n+1}{2} + n$, always moving northwest, but another follows a "boustrophedon" order. Or maybe it doesn't really matter?

Comment: @Todd Trimble: It doesn't matter because $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(n,m)$. Even if they weren't identically equal, they differ on a proportion going to $0$.

Comment: It doesn't matter asymptotically, then. (Manfred also asked about an exact formula.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble as I wrote in my question, I refer *Cantor's* enumeration; that can be interpreted as "the one Cantor used". In case of doubt sort primarily according to  numerator+denominator and resolve equality by sorting according to numerator/denominator in ascending order in both cases.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't read Cantor's paper (which paper is it, anyway?). Please consider editing in your understanding of the scheme into the question, so that the question becomes self-contained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that you are asking about an asymptotic formula for the cardinality of the set $\left\{\frac{n}{m} : n + m \leq x\right\}$, as $x \to +\infty$, where $n$ and $m$ are positive integers. If so, the answer is the following

$$\#\left\{\frac{n}{m} : n + m \leq x\right\} = \sum_{k \leq x} \sum_{\substack{n + m = k \\ \gcd(n,m) = 1}} 1 = \sum_{k \leq x} \sum_{\substack{n \leq k - 1 \\ \gcd(n,k) = 1}} 1$$
$$= \sum_{k \leq x} \varphi(k) - 1 = \frac{3}{\pi^2} x^2 + O(x\log x),$$
as $x \to +\infty$, see *F. Mertens, Uber einige asymptotische Gesetze der Zahlentheorie. Crelle’s Journal 77 (1874), 289–338*.

Comment: I am actually looking for an exact formula, but the asymptotic formula is also of value to me.

Comment: $\sum^x\phi(k)-1$ is about as exact a formula as you are going to get.